# Catching new record creation in bounded datagridview

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` that is bounded to some `BindingList` of `Student`s (my class name).
Within my form, I wanna call some method when the user add row to the DataGridView. But, when I register to the `RowsAdded` event, the event launches the method before the record (`Student`) is created, and ofcourse before it's binded to the row. I can't find the correct event in the `DataGirdView` nor in `DataGirdView.DataBinding`.

What its name and where I can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is not mess with the ui events and just watch your BindingList's CollectionChanged event. Of course, this only works if your DataGridView's binding is Mode=TwoWay